# Google Cloud Pub Sub With Service Account

Tags: python, google-cloud-pubsub, google-api-python-client

Hi everyone I am having an issue with pub sub that is driving me nuts. Basically I have a service account with admin priivs for pubsub but I can't get any thing to work and am getting the following error:

> ERROR:root:AuthMetadataPluginCallback "" raised exception!
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/grpc/_plugin_wrapping.py", line 77, in **call**
>       callback_state, callback))
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/auth/transport/grpc.py", line 77, in **call**
>       callback(self._get_authorization_headers(context), None)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/auth/transport/grpc.py", line 61, in _get_authorization_headers
>       self._credentials.before_request(
>   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'before_request'

Code is super simple

```
 from google.cloud import pubsub

 credentials = '/home/airflow/Desktop/test/config/test.json'

 publisher = pubsub.PublisherClient(credentials=credentials)
 topic_path = publisher.topic_path("test-proj", "test")

 for n in range(1, 2):
  data = u'Message number {}'.format(n)
  # Data must be a bytestring
  data = data.encode('utf-8')
  test = publisher.publish(topic_path, data=data).result()
  print(test, "s")
```

Amy help would be really appreciated as the error message doesn't make much sense to me. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The credentials argument for PublisherClient is not a string. It is a [google.auth.credentials.Credentials](http://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.auth.credentials.html) object. The [google-auth-guide](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#service-account-private-key-files) indicates how to create it:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    '/home/airflow/Desktop/test/config/test.json')
```

Comment: You sir are a legend